# Method explanation

Tags: java, android

Fairly new to java and learning android and came across this answer for a question -

I always define a method which does the casting for me in my base activity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends View> T $(int id) {
    return (T) findViewById(id);
}
```

This means instead of:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

You can do:

```
Button btn = $(R.id.btn)
```

Can someone explain the method to me? Especially the use of the $ symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html). And it uses type inference. You can read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), particularly [Target Types section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types).

```
Button btn = $(R.id.btn)
```

Program is expecting `Button` object from the method, so compiler "knows" what to return and what to use in the cast operation.

And yes, `$` is just the name of the method. But I think some more meaningful name will be better.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a core Java construct.

However, `$` is a legal method name in Java, so you can define a method $

```
private static Button $(int resourceIdOfAButton) {
    (Button) findViewById(resourceIdOfAButton);        
}
```

I have never seen this before and would argue that it's best to stick with common Java naming conventions. As in: choose a method name that gives the reader an idea of what it does.

**Side note:**

Could this maybe be the output of *obfuscated* code?

Comment: May be it comes from jQuery? :)

Comment: @SergeyGlotov luckily jQuery is JS, not Java

Comment: But I think he's right there-  it was written by someone who used/likes jquery, and wanted to use the same semantics.  I'd also advise against this-  it will turn compile time bugs into run time bugs, costing you time in the end.